# How to preserve event order per key in Structured Streaming Repartitioning By Key?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

I want to write a structured spark streaming Kafka consumer which reads data from a one partition Kafka topic, repartitions the incoming data by "key" to 3 spark partitions while keeping the messages ordered per key, and writes them to another Kafka topic with 3 partitions.

I used `Dataframe.repartition(3, $"key")` which I believe uses HashPartitioner. Code is provided below.

When I executed the query with fixed-batch interval trigger type, I visually verified the output messages were in the expected order. My assumption is that order is not guaranteed on the resulting partition. I am looking to receive some affirmation or veto on my assumption in terms of code pointers in the spark code repo or documentation.

I also tried using `Dataframe.sortWithinPartitions`, however this does not seem to be supported on streaming data frame without aggregation.

One option I tried was to convert the Dataframe to RDD and apply `repartitionAndSortWithinPartitions` which repartitions the RDD according to the given partitioner and, within each resulting partition, sort records by their keys. However, then I cannot use this RDD in the query.writestream operation to write the result in the output Kafka topic.

1. Is there a data frame repartitioning API that helps sort the repartitioned data in the streaming context?
2. Are there any other alternatives?
3. Does the default trigger type or fixed-interval trigger type for micro-batch execution provide any sort of message ordering guarantees?

Incoming data:

[image]

```
case class KVOutput(key: String, ts: Long, value: String, spark_partition: Int)

val df = spark.readStream.format("kafka")
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", kafkaBrokers.get)
  .option("subscribe", Array(kafkaInputTopic.get).mkString(","))
  .option("maxOffsetsPerTrigger",30)
  .load()

val inputDf = df.selectExpr("CAST(key AS STRING)","CAST(value AS STRING)")
val resDf = inputDf.repartition(3, $"key")
  .select(from_json($"value", schema).as("kv"))
  .selectExpr("kv.key", "kv.ts", "kv.value")
  .withColumn("spark_partition", spark_partition_id())
  .select($"key", $"ts", $"value", $"spark_partition").as[KVOutput]
  .sortWithinPartitions($"ts", $"value")
  .select($"key".cast(StringType).as("key"), to_json(struct($"*")).cast(StringType).as("value"))

val query = resDf.writeStream
  .format("kafka")
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", kafkaBrokers.get)
  .option("topic", kafkaOutputTopic.get)
  .option("checkpointLocation", checkpointLocation.get)
  .start()
```

When I submit this application, it fails with

```
8/11/08 22:13:20 ERROR ApplicationMaster: User class threw exception: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Sorting is not supported on streaming DataFrames/Datasets, unless it is on aggregated DataFrame/Dataset in Complete output mode;;
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Michal for embedding the images. My post looks much better :)